Do I need both cpe + packageUrl in suppression for dependency-check
I am writing guidelines to help a user to write a good dependency-check suppression entry.
Does a suppression require both a packageUrl and a cpe for the suppression? If the answer is "sometimes", then: why/when? I was under the impression that just the packageUrl would do and am confused as to what the cpe adds.
A broader way of phrasing this question could be: is the following an acceptable minimum set of standardised requirements for a suppression:

packageUrl
cve
until
notes

I have had success previously using only the packageUrl and cve to identify a suppression. I am just unsure what a cpe adds.
